# How to insert an image from PHP into PDF 1.7

Tags: php, pdf, fpdi

I'm creating a web app that allows a canvas form to insert an image from a HTML canvas into a particular position in multiple PDF files. I had this working with python flask as a back-end but the people that I'm making it for only want it in PHP. I have tried using libraries like FPDI but they only work with PDF versions up to 1.4 while the PDF files we are using are version 1.7.

Does anyone know any possible libraries that can help me solve this issue. I would prefer not to convert the PDF files if possible.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With TCPDF you can insert images into a PDF (v.1.7) file:

#### Requirements

```
composer require tecnickcom/tcpdf
```

#### Example

```php
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$pdf = new TCPDF();
$pdf->setPDFVersion('1.7');
$pdf->setAutoPageBreak(true);
$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);

$pdf->AddPage();

// Insert image
$pdf->setJPEGQuality(100);
$pdf->image(__DIR__ . '/example.jpg', 10, 10);

// Close and output PDF document
//$pdf->output('doc.pdf', 'I');

// Save the pdf file
$content = $pdf->output('', 'S');
file_put_contents('example.pdf', $content);
```

Comment: Daniel, he asks for support of reading PDFs with the version 1.7 and not for creating them ;-) Gruß Jan

Comment: Hi Jan :-) In this case, the title and the question were slightly misleading. Gruss Daniel

Answer (score 0):

We (Setasign, creator of FPDI) offer a commercial [add-on](https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi-pdf-parser/details/) that let you import PDFs which uses a compression technic that was introduced in PDF 1.5.

You may also try to downgrade these documents with an external program. I'm aware of some people using Ghostscript for this.

Generally you should know that you do not insert an image into the existing PDF but you create a completely new PDF while importing a single page into a reusable structure which you place onto a newly created page. On top of this you place the image.

[With FPDI you cannot edit a PDF document](https://www.setasign.com/support/faq/fpdi/can-i-edit-a-pdf-document-with-fpdi/#question-82).